# Python- Parse or Read text file with different string length

Tags: python, parsing, text-files, string-length

Content of my Logfile “.log” or “.txt” (Info: the following numbers are lines):

1. Sending Event[ts=19s (00:03:18.243); msg=com.[messageType=MessageOutputType{messageId=840, Before=0, After=0},relPosition=233,  Position=0.9949437244446684, Number=14,timestamp=-14588,segmentId=12 ,vehiclePos=Position{lon=0.008228562772274017, lat=0.0}]]
2. Different String .. not starting with Sending Event
3. Different String .. not starting with Sending Event
4. Sending Event[ts=20s (00:03:18.243); msg=com.[messageType=MessageOutputType{messageId=840},relPosition=234,  Position=0.9949437244446684, Number=14,timestamp=-14588,segmentId=12 ,vehiclePos=Position{lon=0.008228562772274017, lat=0.0}]]
5. Different String.. not starting with Sending Event
6. Sending Event[ts=21s (00:03:18.243); msg=com.[messageType=MessageOutputType{messageId=840, Before=0, After=0}, Number=14,timestamp=-14588,segmentId=12 ,vehiclePos=Position{lon=0.008228562772274017, lat=0.0}]]

In Each line i have repetitive different strings. I want to have the information from the line starting with "Sending Event".
In the line with Sending Event i have different string length and different numbers of variables and values.

**I want to get the values of the variables for each "Sending Event" line plotting the value against the time.**

For Example “ts” = Time and “relPosition” = Variable

**Possible Output for ts and relPosition:**

[19, 233]

[20, ]

[21, 234]

…

How can I extract the Data ?  I want to do the same for “segmentId” or other variables.

I tried with "import re" but got different problems, maybe you can give me an Python2.7 example ?

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("filename.log") as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('Sending Event'):
            l = line[14:].replace('; msg=com.[messageType=MessageOutputType{', ',').replace(' ,vehiclePos=Position{', ', ').replace('}', '')
            d = {i.strip().split('=')[0]: i.strip().split('=')[1] for i in l.split(',')}
            print([d['ts'].split('s')[0], d['relPosition'] if 'relPosition' in d.keys() else '', d['segmentId']])
```

Note that `d` is a dictionary that contains all variables. You can access and print them by `d['variable_name`]`.

Output:

```
['19', '233', '12']
['20', '234', '12']
['21', '', '12']
```

Comment: Thank you, but i got this **Error --> d = {i.strip().split('=')[0]: i.strip().split('=')[1] for i in l.split(',')} IndexError: list index out of range**. And **i forgot i have also lines without starting with "Sending Event"** i have to find first the line starting with "Sending Event. **I edit my Description.**

Comment: Ok, I have updated the answer to filter out the different lines.